# Vertical Timeline CodyHouse, choose side (not alternative)

Tags: javascript, html, css, timeline

I need to use a vertical timeline in my application, and I find this:

https://codyhouse.co/gem/vertical-timeline/

The problem is that the cards are alternate and I want to choose the sequence side cards. I need to choose by css class to force the next card to be show in the right or left side.

I know the class I have to change is .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even)
but I don't know how!

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question would benefit from including how the solution linked "places" the "cards" on both sides of the time-line alternately. (Options are numerous, including separate classes, (different) attributes/values - just don't "open code".)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper{
  max-width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.wrapper .element{
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.wrapper .element:before{
  position: absolute;
  content:'';
  width: 20px;
  top: 10px;
  right: -15px;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
}
.wrapper .element:first-child{
  margin-top: 0;
}
.wrapper .element:nth-child(2n){
  margin-left: 110%;
}
.wrapper .element:nth-child(2n):before{
  right: auto;
  left: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
  <div class="element">text text<p>text</p>texttext</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8yo1c2ze/